# Changing large number of Ajax calls to one call

Tags: ajax, shopify

I have created a large quick-order form on Shopify, involving about 200 products. Each product has a text box, where the user can enter the quantity that they want. As they enter a number in the textbox, the data needed to add the item to the cart is added to an array.  When the user presses "add to cart", a function then runs through the array, passing each piece of data to the cart via Ajax.

The issue I am having is that, in the case that the user adds a lot of products, let's say 50, the process takes a long time to run.  Adding 50 products would then involve 50 Ajax calls.  I have tried passing the entire array in one call, but the problem is that Shopify does not give me access to the PHP part of the Ajax, so I cannot update it to accommodate the data coming across as an Array.

Is there another way that this process can be sped up?  A way to send the data in one Ajax call, without editing the PHP.

Here is my JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var updated = new Array();

  /**
  ** Creates array of textboxes that have input.
  ** Updates the array, if a textbox's input is changed.
  **/
  $("input[type=number]").on("input", function() {  

    var new_item = true;
    var variant = $(this).parent().children("input[type=hidden]").val();        
    var quantity = $(this).val();

    if(updated.length <= 0) {
      updated.push({
        variant_id: variant,        
        quantity: quantity
      });
    }

    else if (updated.length > 0) {
      for (var key in updated) {
       if(parseInt(updated[key].variant_id) == variant) {
         updated[key].quantity = quantity;
         new_item = false;
         return false;
       } 
     }

     if(new_item == true) {
       updated.push({
         variant_id: variant,        
         quantity: quantity
      });
     }
    }

  });

  /**
  ** On press of "Add to Cart", runs through array of textboxes and posts values to cart.
  **/
  $("#submit-table").click(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val("Adding to Cart...");

    var toAdd = new Array();

    for(i=0; i < updated.length; i++){

      if(updated[i].quantity === "") {
            updated[i].quantity = 0; 
      }

      toAdd.push({
        variant_id: updated[i].variant_id,        
        quantity: updated[i].quantity
      });
    }

    function moveAlong(){
      if (toAdd.length) {

        var request = toAdd.shift();
        var tempId= request.variant_id;
        var tempQty = request.quantity;

        var params = {
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/cart/add.js',
          data: 'quantity='+tempQty+'&id='+tempId,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(line_item) { 
            moveAlong();

          },
          error: function() {
            moveAlong();

          }
        };
        $.ajax(params);
      }
      else {                
        document.location.href = '/cart';
      }  
    };
    moveAlong();
  });
});
```

Comment: Are line item properties in play, or are we 100% certain that we only care about variant ID and quantity?

Comment: This might help you: https://cartjs.org/